# Change Timer from var = 1200 to display mm:ss that the title

Tags: javascript, svg, timer

i'm working on a circular timer where the code relates to a svg drawing. 
I currently have the following js code. This displays the timer counting up from -1200 to get to 0 but doesn't display the "-" so looks like it's counting down. Please can someone tell me a way of using the same code but making it count from 20 minutes so it seems as if its a digital clock?

```
var seconds = 1200; /* how long the timer runs for */
var initialOffset = '440';
var i = -1200;
var interval = setInterval(


function() {
    $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(i*(initialOffset/seconds)));
    $('h2').text(Math.abs(i));
    if (i == 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    i++;  
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Math.abs() which will return positive number. abs(-1200) would results in 1200

You could just append Minus (-) in front of your value like below

```
$('h2').text("-" + Math.abs(i));
```

Comment: That's not really what I was looking for tbh mate. I want a way to convert the timer from 1200 seconds into 20 minutes and 0 seconds without having to change the entire set of code, if that's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Given `i` seconds, you can convert that into minutes/seconds with:

```
var secs = Math.abs(i); // convert your negative count to positive
var m = Math.floor(secs/60);
var s = i%60;
```

To display these as a clock, you will want to pad the second value to ensure it is always two-digits numbers (ie, "09" instead of "9"):

```
var clock = m+":"+(s<10?"0":"")+s;
```